# Inno Setup - Post Processing

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to build an MD5 checksum file of the setup file generated by Inno Setup. I've found the pre-processor and was wondering if there is a way to do some processing once the 'setup' output file has been created. 
It needs to run at the compile time not during installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are automating your build, just use command-line compiler from a batch file (or any other script).

And as a next step, [run a tool to calculate the checksum](https://superuser.com/q/245775/213663).

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\ISCC.exe" Example1.iss
certutil -hashFile mysetup.exe MD5
```

---

Alternatively, use [Inno Script Studio](https://www.kymoto.org/products/inno-script-studio) (clone of Inno Setup).

It has `[PostCompile]` section. In its GUI, it's "Post Compilation Steps".

Comment: The batch file is surly an option, but a bit messy. Need to remember/document to use it. I was seeing the md5 a part of the generated output, so it really should be part of the setup script.