# Inno Setup - How to copy the created setup file

Tags: inno-setup

I want to copy the created setup file to a network directory. I think the `[Run]` section will be the best position to do this, but I cannot not found any possibility to call my copy function. Any idea to this issue?

Also, is it possible to use variables declared in the [setup] section for the copy path?

My procedure will be like this (trying to use the variables):

```pascal
[Code]
procedure CopyFile();
begin
  FileCopy('{OutputDir}/{OutputBaseFilename}',
    'V:/Service/Software/ASCDeploy/Prod/Asc.Tools.FileCopy/{OutputBaseFilename}', False);
end;
```

Comment: So why don't you set `OutputDir` to the network directory?

Comment: Because i need the OutputDir for internal purposes. The other file is our global installation directory.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to run any code after Inno Setup finishes compiling - At least not in the original Inno Setup.

See also [Inno Setup - Post Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40598964/850848).

Comment: Why not run the installer in a batch file. Then you can copy the output to another location in the batch.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Sure, that's what my answer in the linked question suggests.